# Importance of "Bundle identifier"

Tags: iphone, cocoa, plist

What is the importance of "Bundle identifier" in info.plist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle identifier is supposed to uniquely identify your app. You don't change it after a release, never, and you can then change the other stuff (display name for example).

It's all essential regarding mobile provisioning profiles and in-app purchase: you link an in-app purchase with your bundle identifier. And you can create a mobile provisioning just for your bundle identifier (not for com.yourcompany.* or fr.ecomposite.*).

Answer (score 0):

The bundle identifier should be the same as the app id that you resigstered on the development portal.  When you go to deploy the app in the app store it will check the bundle identifier to make sure you are uploading a regiastered app.